# Why is Laravel Sail not wanting to start the when running ./vendor/bin/sail up?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

When running ./vendor/bin/sail up, it just won't work.
This is after installing a brand new version using:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash

cd example-app
 
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

## System

- MacBook Air
- Apple M2 Chip
- macOS: Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)

## Docker

I've gone to the lengths of completely uninstalling and re-installing it

## Error that I get

```
#0 196.1 ## Running `apt-get update` for you...
#0 196.1 
#0 196.1 + apt-get update
#0 196.2 Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease [4563 B]
#0 196.3 Get:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy/main arm64 Packages [776 B]
#0 196.3 Err:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy/main arm64 Packages
#0 196.3   File has unexpected size (778 != 776). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 23.34.82.11 443]
#0 196.3   Hashes of expected file:
#0 196.3    - Filesize:776 [weak]
#0 196.3    - SHA256:4cdc71073957aaffbea511d99669cc4fa98b752eab966068a023558555e0ab92
#0 196.3    - SHA1:0b9c08bd020fac9bc1d05b3008fe7aeee3d1a182 [weak]
#0 196.3    - MD5Sum:fc5eace817a48e2a439589628112ec00 [weak]
#0 196.3   Release file created at: Thu, 13 Apr 2023 14:12:05 +0000
#0 196.3 Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
#0 196.4 Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
#0 196.5 Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
#0 196.5 Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
#0 196.6 Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
#0 196.7 Fetched 4563 B in 1s (7785 B/s)
#0 196.7 Reading package lists...
#0 197.1 E: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x/dists/jammy/main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (778 != 776). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 23.34.82.11 443]
#0 197.1    Hashes of expected file:
#0 197.1     - Filesize:776 [weak]
#0 197.1     - SHA256:4cdc71073957aaffbea511d99669cc4fa98b752eab966068a023558555e0ab92
#0 197.1     - SHA1:0b9c08bd020fac9bc1d05b3008fe7aeee3d1a182 [weak]
#0 197.1     - MD5Sum:fc5eace817a48e2a439589628112ec00 [weak]
#0 197.1    Release file created at: Thu, 13 Apr 2023 14:12:05 +0000
#0 197.1 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#0 197.1 Error executing command, exiting
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils librsvg2-bin     && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null     && echo \"deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev        php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd php8.2-imagick        php8.2-curl        php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring        php8.2-xml php8.2-zip php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap        php8.2-intl php8.2-readline        php8.2-ldap        php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole        php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug     && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null     && echo \"deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null     && echo \"deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I've also tried on Windows and getting the same thing. It's occurring on both my existing and new applications. I even tried it on Windows without updating to the latest version of Docker and Ubuntu, and getting issues then too.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried ./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache, in case someone cares to answer that.

Comment: So in the error message it says 'failed to fetch' with the node library and 'unexpected filesize, mirror sync in progress'. Best thing you can do is try again later. *Publish your sail assets*, you're going to need them later when troubleshooting.

Comment: And that's pretty much what happened. Waited for a while and it started to work~ish. I posted it on Laracasts and it looks like others are having the same issue.